# Regular expression does not allow a dash

Tags: regex

Currently using a text field and need some validation for capturing days of a month.

```
^(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:(?: *- *(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?(?: *, *(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?: *- *(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?)+)?$
```

My regular expression will allow a value like
`1-30, 27, 3, 13`.

But not
`10-27`.

Any suggestions on getting both examples to evaluate correctly?

Tried searching for examples allowing a dash by adding - but received the same result.

Comment: While the regular expressions are a powerful tool, using them this way produces code that is difficult to read, understand and verify. Use a simpler regular expression like `[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}` to identify the components then validate each component using other functions provided by the language or the tool that you use. What language or tool do you use for this processing?

Comment: Tokens in regex only match a single character. You have to use quantifiers to match multiple characters with a single token. For this reason, `1-30` is not doing what you think it is. Assuming you're using it in square brackets, `[1-30]` is effectively telling the engine to match anything between 1 and 3 OR 0. `[10-27]` would also work the same way. It will match 1 OR anything between 0 and 2 OR 7. A correct way of matching 1-30 would be something like `[1-2][0-9]|30`. From 10-27 would be `1[0-9]|2[0-7]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
^  # start of string
 (?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])  # a day pattern
 (?:            # start of an optional non-capturing group
    \ *-\ *     # a hyphen enclosed with zero or more spaces
    (?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) # a day pattern
 )?             # end of the optional group
 (?:            # start of an optional non-capturing group
   \ *,\ *(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) # comma inside optional spaces + day pattern
   (?:\ *-\ *(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))? # an optional sequence of hyphen inside optional spaces + day pattern
 )* # repeat zero or more times
$  # end of string
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/usuRwf/1).

A one liner:

```
^(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?: *- *(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?(?: *, *(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?: *- *(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?)*$
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/usuRwf/2).